# Run a command on every file, with a flag argument that depends on the filename

Tags: shell, find

Suppose I have a folder containing files with names like

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file2.txt
```

etc.  I would like to run a command on each of them, like so:

```
mycommand file1.txt -o file1-processed.txt
mycommand file2.txt -o file2-processed.txt
mycommand file3.txt -o file3-processed.txt
```

etc.

There are several similar questions on this site - the difference is that I want to insert the `-processed` test into the middle of the file name, before the extension.

It seems like `find` should be the tool for the job. If it wasn't for the `-o` flag I could do

```
find *.txt -exec mycommand "{}" ";"
```

However, the `{}` syntax gives the whole file name, e.g. `file1.txt` etc., so I can't add the "`-processed`" in between the filename and its extension. A similar problem exists with using a simple bash `for` loop.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this task, using `find` or otherwise?

Comment: FYI, `find *.txt` will find all the files ***and directories*** in the current directory whose names end with `.txt`, and then ***everything*** under those directories (if any).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If all the files to be processed are in the same folder, you don't need to use `find`, and can make do with native shell globbing.

```
for foo in *.txt ; do
  mycommand "${foo}" -o "${foo%.txt}-processed.txt"
done
```

The shell idiom `${foo%bar}` removes the smallest suffix string matching the pattern `bar` from the value of `foo`, in this case the `.txt` extension, so we can replace it with the suffix you want.

Comment: To be sure that `mycommand` is only invoked on _regular files_, one could insert `[ -f "$foo" ] && ` or `test -f "$foo" && ` in front of `mycommand ...`.

Answer (score 6):

If you write a script to be run on various systems and portability is a concern, then nothing beats `for` loops and `${var%sfx}` from *user1404316*'s answer.

However, if you are looking for a convenient way to do similar things on your own system, then I heartily recommend [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), which is basically `xargs` on steroids.  Here's a solution for your particular task:

```
parallel mycommand {} -o {.}-processed.txt ::: *.txt
```

It will take a list of strings after `:::` (shell would expand `*.txt` to a list of matching filenames) and run `mycommand {} -o {.}-processed.txt` for each string, replacing `{}` with input string (just like `xargs`) and `{.}` with filename without extension.

You can feed list of input strings via `stdin` (*xargs*-way), to pair it with `find` or `locate`, but I rarely need anything more than `zsh`'s extended globs.

Take a look at [GNU Parallel tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) to get the idea of what it can do.  I use it all the time for batch converts, extracting archives to sudirectories etc.

Answer (score 4):

This adapts [user1404316’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/420365/80216#420366) to work with `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' \
   -exec sh -c 'for file do mycommand "$file" -o "${file%.txt}-processed.txt"; done' sh {} +
```

(You can type that all on one line; just leave out the `\`. 
I broke it into two lines for readability.)

---

Another way to format it for readability, that makes the embedded shell script a little bit clearer:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '
  for file
  do
    mycommand "$file" -o "${file%.txt}-processed.txt";
  done
' sh {} +
```

---

Basically, it creates an unnamed shell script:

```
for file
do
    mycommand "$file" -o "${file%.txt}-processed.txt"
done
```

(that’s the string between the single quotes, `'…'`, unrolled)
and passes it to the shell as a command (`sh -c`)
with the names of all your `.txt` files as parameters. 
(You generally don’t need to quote `{}`,
and you don’t need curly braces in `"$file"`.)

Comment: Very nice solution; this is exactly what I was going to write if you hadn't already done so.  :)  I added an edit; see if you like it—but I didn't clean up the surrounding text in light of the edit so you may want to have a look.

Comment: @Wildcard: Your edit strikes me as a little verbose, but I suppose it might be useful to others. I don’t see anything in the surrounding text that really needs to be changed.

Comment: That's fine then.  If I were to really go all-out to edit it, I would leave just the line-wrapped version I posted, since it makes the unnamed shell script (within the `'...'`) easy to see without needing to present it again separately.  But, I'm a bit of a perfectionist about such things.  :)

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
for f (*.txt) mycommand -o $f:r-processed.txt -- $f
```

- avoid using options after non-option arguments. That's supported by few commands, and for most of those that do (like the ones using the GNU getopt API), not when `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment. That also means you can't work around problems with file names that start with `-` (like we do with `--` here) other than by using `./-file-.txt`.
- `for var (values) cmd` is a handy short form of for loop reminiscent of `perl`'s syntax.
- `zsh` is one of those rare shells where `$f` doesn't need to be quoted (assuming it's not in a mode where it's emulating other shells)
- `$file:r` expands to the *root name* of the file, that is with the extension removed like in `csh`. It's more or less equivalent to the Korn shell's `${f%.*}` with the added benefit that it won't cross `/` boundaries (with `f=./foo`, `$f:r` is `./foo` instead of the empty string), though it doesn't apply here.
- that excludes hidden files (like `.foo.txt`). If you want them included, you can add the `D` glob qualifier (`*.txt(D)`), but you may want to  exclude a  file called `.txt` alone as then the output file would be `-processed.txt` which wouldn't be ideal (and also would not be hidden), by using `?*.txt(D)`.
- if there's no `*.txt` file in the current directory, that will fail with an error (and thankfully not run `mycommand` at all contrary to with other shells). If you want the loop just not to do anything instead, you can add the `N` glob qualifier (`*.txt(N)`).
- Note that that includes all `*.txt` files regardless of their type (regular, symlink, directory, fifo, socket, device...). If you want to only consider *regular* files, you can add the `.` glob qualifier (or `-.` to also include symlinks to regular files, that is, the files for which `[ -f "$f" ]` would return true). So, with all of the above applied:

  ```
  for f (?*.txt(ND.)) mycommand -o $f:r-processed.txt -- $f
  ```
- to search for `*.txt` files in subdirectories as well, change it to `**/*.txt` (with the `D` flag it also descends in hidden directories).

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `find`, `sed` and `xargs` might work, if you need recursion and more complex string substitution:

```
find . -iname '*.txt' -printf "%p\0-o\0%p\0" | sed -z '3~3s/\.txt$/-processed&/' | xargs -0 -n 3 echo mycommand
```

Example:

```
$ find
.
./bar baz.txt
./foo.txt
$ find . -iname '*.txt' -printf "%p\0-o\0%p\0" | sed -z '3~3s/\.txt$/-processed&/' | xargs -0 -n 3 echo mycommand
mycommand ./bar baz.txt -o ./bar baz-processed.txt
mycommand ./foo.txt -o ./foo-processed.txt
```

The `-printf "%p\0-o\0%p\0"` prints the file path twice, with `-o` in between, delimited with the ASCII NUL character, and the `sed` command inserts a `-processed` before a trailing `.txt` on every third line. Then `xargs` runs the command with three arguments at a time, which would be the filename, `-o`, and the edited filename.

Answer (score 0):

One could always make use of `basename` command, which is part of GNU coreutils. From the directory with the files:

```
for filename in ./file*.txt
do
    mycommand "$filename" -o ./"$(basename -s '.txt' "$filename" )"-processed.txt
done
```